# Save two TextBox as DateTime asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I have two textBox in first i have Date in this format : 2012.09.20 and in the second i have Time in this format: 15:30:00. In database i have Column name "Eventstart" type: DateTime. Now i like to take the value from two textbox and put them in something like this:

```
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxEnd.Text) + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxTimeEnd.Text);
```

But give me this error : Error  2   Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate your TextBoxes text and use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with format `"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"`

After concatenating the text you should have: `"2012.09.20 15:30:00"`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBoxEnd.Text + " " + TextBoxTimeEnd.Text, 
                                  "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you should be using:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxEnd.Text);
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxTimeEnd.Text);
DateTime combined = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Or you could combine the *text* and then parse that:

```
DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxEnd.Text + " " +
                                       TextBoxTimeEnd.Text);
```

I'm not sure I'd use `Convert.ToDateTime` at all though - if you know the exact format that the textbox will be in, you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. You should work out which culture to use in that case though. If it's a genuinely fixed precise format, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` might be appropriate. If it's a culture-specific format, then use the user's culture.

You might also want to use an alternative UI representation which doesn't use textboxes at all, which would avoid potentially troubling string conversions.

Answer (score 0):

First concatenate both the values and then add it to a DateTime variable

example:

```
string str = date.Text + time.Text;  // assumed date and time are textboxes

DateTime dt=new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(str,dt); // returns datetime in dt if it is valid
```

Comment: `Add` takes a `TimeSpan` object, not another `DateTime`, for the obvious reason that adding two dates doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @verdesmarald sorry that was mistake. I thought it takes but there is no method for add datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxEnd.Text) + TimeSpan.Parse(TextBoxTimeEnd.Text);
```